# Storing image resources in custom folders and accessing them through XML?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to add a folder to my Apps directory, in which I store a group of image files which I can then use in the same manner as I would with the following?

```
android:background="@drawable/image"
```

I have over 50 images that I am using for my application, and it would be really great if I could store those in separate folders rather than just the one.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was just trying to be polite. Thank You anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

In order to use resources in your XML they must be declared in one of the subdirectories of the res folder.  For drawables, the default will be drawable and then there are size and dpi specific directories you can use if you are providing multiple versions of the same image.